# integral of 3d gaussian with hollow integral space

Tags: 3d, gaussian-integral

I am trying compute the triple integral of a 3D Gaussian within a sphere hollow space. My questions are at the end.

You can think the problem in this manner. There is a very large ball whose center is hollow. The density follows 3D gaussian distribution, now I want to compute the mass of the hollow ball.

The 3D Gaussian is:

$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{3}{2}} \sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z} \exp \left[ -\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} - \frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{2\sigma_y^2} - \frac{(z-\mu_z)^2}{2\sigma_z^2} \right] ,
$$

where $$ \quad \Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_x^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_y^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sigma_z^2\end{pmatrix},$$

And the integral is $ \int \limits_{V} f(x,y,z)dv$, and $V$ is the area of $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} >= R$, $R \in [0, +\infty]$. After integration, it should be a function of $R$.

For further simplification, I treated $\mu_x = \mu_y = \mu_z = 0$, and $\sigma_z = \sigma_y = \sigma_z = \sigma$.

And the original equation became:
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{3}{2}} \sigma^3} \exp \left[ -\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{2\sigma^2} \right].
$$

Followings are my integration process, and I am not sure whether I am correct or not.

$$
\int \limits_{V} f(x,y,z)dv = \int \limits_{V} f(x,y,z)dx dy dz
$$

$$
= \int \limits_{V} \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{3}{2}} \sigma^3} \exp \left( {- \frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) \rho^2 \sin \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{3}{2}} \sigma^3} \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int \limits_{0}^{\pi} sin \phi d\phi \int \limits_{R}^{+\infty} \rho^2 \exp \left( {- \frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) d\rho
$$

$$
\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta = 2\pi;
\int \limits_{0}^{\pi} d\phi = -\cos(\pi) + \cos(0) = 2;
$$

Thus, it becomes
$$
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma^3} \int \limits_{R}^{+\infty} \rho^2 \exp \left( {- \frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) d\rho
$$

$$
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma} \int \limits_{R}^{+\infty} \rho \exp \left( {- \frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) d{\left(\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}
$$

$$
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma} \int \limits_{R}^{+\infty} -\rho \cdot d \left( {\exp{\left[ -\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]}} \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma} \left[ {-\rho\exp{\left( -\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}} \Big|_R^{+\infty} + \int \limits_R^{+\infty} \exp \left({-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2} }\right) d\rho \right]
$$

As $lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{e^{x^2}} = lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{dx}{dx}}{d e^{x^2}} = lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2x e^{x^2}} = 0$

The original integration becomes
$$
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma} \left[ \left[ 0 + R\exp{\left( -\frac{R^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}\right] + \int \limits_R^{+\infty} \exp \left({-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2} }\right) d\rho \right]
$$

The integration in the equation can be calculated separately
$$
\int \limits_R^{+\infty} \exp \left({-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2} }\right) d\rho
$$
$$
= \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma \int \limits_R^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma }\exp \left({-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2} }\right) d\rho
$$
This is the normal distribution function, which can be easily calculated as

$$
= \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma \left[ 1 - \int \limits_{-\infty}^R \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma }\exp \left({-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2} }\right) d\rho \right]
$$

$$
= \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{2} \left[ 1 + erf \left( \frac{R}{\sqrt 2 \sigma} \right) \right] \right]
$$

$$
= \frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt2}\sigma \left[ 1 - erf \left( \frac{R}{\sqrt2 \sigma}\right) \right] 
$$
Plug the result in the original equation 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma} \left[ R\exp{\left( -\frac{R^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)} + \frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt2}\sigma \left[ 1 - erf \left( \frac{R}{\sqrt2 \sigma}\right) \right] \right]
$$
$$
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma} \left[ R\exp{\left( -\frac{R^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)} + \frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt2}\sigma \left[ 1 - erf \left( \frac{R}{\sqrt2 \sigma}\right) \right] \right]
$$
$$
= 1 - erf{\left( \frac{R}{\sqrt2\sigma} \right)}+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma} R\exp{\left( -\frac{R^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}
$$

1. Is my calculation correct? I am not that confident of it, as have not been using this for a very long time.
2. The problem has physical meaning when integral it from R to $\infty$. If I need to do the integral from $\infty$ to R, will the the sign be revised?

Comment: The case where $\sigma=\sigma_x=\sigma_y=\sigma_z$ is equivalent to a $\chi^2$ distribution with three degrees of freedom.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cdf+of+chi+squared+distribution+with+three+degrees+of+freedom

Comment: I think your answer to the case where all the sigma's are the same is correct.  I got the same answer using a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: @irchans Thanks very much for the input. Did not know χ2  distribution before, but glad to see it is correct. But for the case σx≠σy≠σz , do you  think how it could be? And if I integrate it from $\infty$ to 0, will the sign be revised?

Comment: By convention, $\int_{x=a}^b f(x)dx= - \int_{x=b}^a f(x) dx$ for any real or complex valued function  $f$.   I don't think that I can do anything analytic when $\sigma_x\ne\sigma_y$.  You can get very accurate numerical approximations in those cases.  What is  your application?

Comment: Also, it is not too hard to get rough bounds on the integral.

Comment: it is for uncertainty modeling, If you a robot arm, it moves in 3D space, and for some reasons, it has position accuracy in each direction, now I want to the overall uncertainty to the target location. I agree that it is not a complex problem to use the numerical method, but a function would be easier there for understanding.

Comment: @user2018557   I wrote a lot of guidance and tracking software.  When the customer wanted to reduce the error ellipsoid to a single radius, I usually used the trace of the covariance matrix M= trace(ExpectedValue[ $(X-\overline{X})(X-\overline{X})^T$]).  As you probably know, the trace of the covariance matrix is the expected value of the distance from the mean squared.  If you need to bound the probability of falling outside of a sphere, you could figure out a pretty tight bound.

Answer (score 1):

When I typed

"1 - FunctionExpand[ CDF[ ChiSquareDistribution[3], x][[1, 1, 1]]] /. 
  x -> (R/s)^2 // Simplify//PowerExpand//Simplify"

into Mathematica, Mathematica returns

$$1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt{2} s}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} R e^{-\frac{R^2}{2
   s^2}}}{s}$$
which is exactly the same as your result.

I worked on the case where $\sigma_x\ne \sigma_y \ne \sigma_z$, but I did not make much progress.

Comment: That is a really wow. I did not have much experience with Mathematica, it feels so great to see it is confirmed. Thank you so much. And please let me know if you have any progress on the case of $ \sigma_x\ne \sigma_y \ne \sigma_z$